Brownian motion is Locally Holder contiuous $ |B(t)-B(s)| \leq C|t-s|^\alpha, \quad 0 \leq s, t \leq N, $
The following is taken from Exercise 22 in section 1.5 of Ligget's continuous time markov processes.
It states that
Use Doob's inequality, Theorem A.42, applied to even powers larger than the fourth in the proof of Theorem 1.21 to obtain the following improvement: for every $N>0$ and every $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$ there is a random variable $C$ so that
$$
|B(t)-B(s)| \leq C|t-s|^\alpha, \quad 0 \leq s, t \leq N,
$$
i.e., the paths are locally Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha$. (It follows from Exercise 1.30 below that this is not true if $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$.)
Doob's inequality as stated in the appendix is the following
If $\{M_k, 0 \leq k \leq n\}$ is a nonnegative submartingale, then
$$
\lambda P\left(\max _{0 \leq k \leq n} M_k \geq \lambda\right) \leq E M_n, \quad \lambda>0,
$$
and as a consequence,
$$
E\left(\max _{0 \leq k \leq n} M_k\right)^2 \leq 4 E M_n^2 .
$$
I won't put the proof of theorem 1.21 here since it's too long. I'm struggling to figure out how to approach this and some guidance would be greatly appreciated!

It seems like they want you to use the arguments used in the proof of theorem 1.21

@Kakashi sorry, but could i have some more details?

I don't know how to solve this, I was just guessing that it wants you to mimick the proof. I could be wrong.
